# Using sed with a variable in the pattern

Tags: sed, rename, mv

I am trying to rename a couple of files with the same extensions with a differing variable in the middle. I have tried the following with no luck as to what I wish to accomplish.

file: `cKO_mESC_Rep_1_H3K27Ac.gc_corrected.bam`

```
INBAM=$(ls *_*.gc_corrected.bam)
INPUT=$(echo $INBAM | sed 's/_*.gc_corrected.bam/_input.gc_corrected.bam/g')

echo $INPUT 
cKO_mESC_Rep_1_H3K27Ac_input.gc_corrected.bam
```

However, I want my output to be `cKO_mESC_Rep_1_input.gc_corrected.bam`

Anyone know what the mistake is? I have tried so many things and I may not be searching using the right keywords to get an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the name of a file AND the desired filename AFTER renaming?  That would make things easier.  And `sed` is likely the wrong tool here anyway.  How about `rename`?

Comment: file name cKO_mESC_Rep_1_H3K27Ac.gc
desired name cKO_mESC_Rep_1_input.gc_corrected.bam

I'm using sed in a loop so that it looks for the paired input file in another folder that has the same perceding name just different variable in front to the extension.

Comment: There are several potential bugs in your script. A better solution is the `rename` command, the one written by Larry Wall (`apt install rename`). It is `sed` for file-names.

Comment: in sed and reg.exp., `_*` means "many `_`".  Instead of `sed 's/_*.gc....` try `sed 's/_.*.gc`  or `sed 's/_[^_]*.gc...`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.

I think you are mixing up "wildcard characters" (a.k.a. "[shell globs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)") with [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) in your use of `sed`.

Your intention clearly is to replace the pattern "underscore, followed by any number of letters and digits, followed by `.gc_corrected.bam`" by `_input.gc_corrected.bam`. Unfortunately, your `sed` expression is flawed in two ways:

- Your matching part uses the shell-typical "wildcard character" notation. However, `sed` expects a regular expression here, and in regular expressions, the `*` does *not* mean "any string of zero or more characters", but "zero or more repetitions of the previous character", so that your expression would replace any pattern consisting of "zero or more underscores, followed by `.gc_corrected.bam`" with the replacement `_input.gc_corrected.bam`. That is why in your case, simply the last underscore before the filename suffix is replaced with `_input`.
- Even so, if you have multiple underscores in your actual filename, a pattern matching "a string consisting of any number of characters" would also include underscores, which may lead to undesired behaviour on the length of the matched string. In particular, regular expressions are greedy, and if not constructed carefully, you might end up replacing the entire `_mESC_Rep_1_H3K27Ac` part of the filename by `_input`.

In your case, the correct regular expression would be:

```
sed 's/_[^_]+\.gc_corrected\.bam/_input.gc_corrected.bam/g'
```

This would replace a string, starting with an underscore `_`, followed by one or more characters *that are not underscores* (`[^_]+`), followed by `.gc_corrected.bam`, with your substitution `_input.gc_corrected.bam`.

**Note also** that in regular expressions, the `.` stands for "any single character" (which in shell globs would be represented by the `?`), so if you want to match a literal `.`, you have to escape it. This is of course not necessary in the replacement string as *that* is not a regular expression.